# Why does my GPUs keeping a high power usage even without any workload?

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Usually, when GPUs are idle, they only keep very low power usages around 15W or so.

However, in my case, they keep a power usages of more than 100W even without any running processes. It's quite strange.

GPUs are RTX3090 and loaded in a Ubuntu18.04 server. The driver version is 460.80.

Output screenshot of command nvidia-smi:
[image: Output screenshot of command nvidia-smi]

Comment: How many monitors do you have attached?  Does the power draw drop if you unplug monitors?

Comment: @Turksarama It's a server actually. So it usually doesn't have monitors attached. And I find when I load a process to device 0, the power usages of the rest unused cards drop to a normal level of about 10W. After I kill the process, the power usages of all of the cards raise again.

Comment: I hope you are not infected with a bitcoin miner.

Comment: @harrymc Is there any method to check whether there exists a backdoor mining process?

Comment: Only running deep antivirus scans by several well-known products (they don't all check the same things).

Comment: @harrymc Thank for your advice. I'll check it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I successfully bring the idle power usages down to normal level. And I think I know what's going on.

All I did is enable the persistce mode by `sudo nvidia-smi -pm 1`. And it works and the idle power usages of all the gpus drop down to the normal level of around 10W.

However, now I think that actually the idle power usages are not as high as I see. I gauss it is because I query the status of these gpus that cause the power usages burst to a high level.

The NVIDIA kernel mode driver must be running and connected to a target GPU device before any user interactions with that device can take place.

When the persistence mode is off, the gpu driver will deinitialize the gpus when no process is accessing. As I use `nvidia-smi` to query the status of these gpus. The driver will firstly initialize the gpus and fetch the status afterwards. It's the initialzation that cause the gpus running in a high power usage. Therefore, I get the wrong information that the gpus power usages are high even without any workload. In fact, it's the status when these gpus are being initialized.

When the persistence mode is on, the gpu will not be deinitialize and thus no need for re-initialzation when queried. So what I see is the real idle power usage.

[image]